# Responsive multi-item flow--two on last line except when two on previous lines

Tags: responsive-design, responsive

**The Situation**

Let's say I've got five divs of equal size, but only four fit side-by-side at max width.

CSS:

```
.container {
  max-width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[Run it here.](https://jsfiddle.net/gnu2bfz7/8/)

**The Wrong Answers**

At max width, we have this:

□□□□
□

Instead of leaving that last item on a row by itself, I'd like to keep it balanced with three on top and two on the bottom:

□□□
□□

That part's easy... unless I want the page to work responsively. If I add a break between the third and fourth items or wrap the last two in a div with clear:both or anything like that, when the width is reduced further, the lines break unnaturally at 2-1-2:

□□
□
□□

**The Goal**

At full width, I'd like the third and fourth items to fall to the second line (3-2). At medium width, I'd like the items to fall as they would naturally, 2-2-1. And, of course, at minimum width, it should be one per line (1-1-1-1-1).

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a way to set the container to skip over certain widths--so that, for instance, if the inherited width is 100px-76px, it skips down to 75px (while the max width is 200px and the min is 50px)?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping the last two items in a div and used @media to set that div to display: inline for certain browser widths.

[You can see it in action here.](https://jsfiddle.net/gnu2bfz7/9/)

CSS:

```
.container {
  max-width: 420px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 323px) {
  div.lastrow {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="lastrow">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```